# python descriptor protocol function prototype declaration

Tags: python, descriptor

I looked through the examples of python descriptor, the usage of descriptor is quite easy, but I don't understand the function prototypes.

```
__get__(self, obj, type=None) --> value

__set__(self, obj, value) --> None

__delete__(self, obj) --> None
```

I mean, if the first `self` parameter refers to the class object, then what does the second parameter `obj` stand for ? The example on the web just ignored the `obj` parameter.

Comment: `self` refers to descriptor itself whereas `obj` refers to object calling it. You can think of `obj` as the owner of the descriptor being defined as its property.

Answer (score 0):

`self` is the *descriptor* object. `obj` is the object the descriptor is being invoked on.